# Apache Commons FileUpload OSGi bundle

Tags: file-upload, osgi, apache-felix, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I got this error installing my bundle in Karaf, I am new to OSGi and Karaf so I can use some help in interpreting the error.

```
Error executing command: Could not start bundle mvn:com.myexample/foobar/0.1.0.SNAPSHOT 
in feature(s) com.myexample.foobar-0.6.0.SNAPSHOT: Unresolved constraint in bundle 
com.myexample.foobar [102]: Unable to resolve 102.0: missing requirement [102.0] 
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.commons.fileupload)
(version>=1.3.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
```

This is in my `feature.xml`

```
    <bundle>mvn:commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3</bundle>
```

and in my POM

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
     <version>1.3</version>
  </dependency>
```

The Maven repository shows the latest version at 1.3 but it may not be the OSGi version if there is one, anyone know where I can find it? I also tried `wrap:mvn` and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.3 has an OSGi manifest and should work as a bundle:

```
$ bnd print -i http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3/commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
[IMPEXP]
Import-Package
  javax.servlet                          
  javax.servlet.http                     
  org.apache.commons.io                  
  org.apache.commons.io.output           

Export-Package
  org.apache.commons.fileupload          {version=1.3}
  org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk     {version=1.3}
  org.apache.commons.fileupload.portlet  {version=1.3}
  org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet  {version=1.3}
  org.apache.commons.fileupload.util     {version=1.3}
```

Comment: THat's what I thought so too, any idea why it isn't working for me? What does the error mean exactly?

Comment: I do not know how Karaf features works but it sounds like it does not install the bundle ... You will need to look at the set of installed bundles and their state. Maybe this bundle is not resolved because it misses commons io?

Comment: Karaf features work quite simple, it's basically a list of bundles to install in one go for easier deployment. Back to the issue, are all dependencies satisfied also for the commons-fileupload (is commons-io installed with this feature?)

Comment: Thanks guys, that was it, I installed commons-io 2.4, BTW what's the difference between Apache commons io vs commons io?

Comment: https://jpm4j.org/#!/search?q=p:org.apache.commons.io%20a:commons-io In contrast what one would expect from convention, the commons-io:commons-io is more recent.